# Center DatePicker Vertically within Form SwiftUI

Tags: forms, swiftui, datepicker

Is there any way to center this datepicker vertically? This is clearly possible if we ditch the `Form` (and use VStack and Spacers), but as a constraint, try to keep the form. Or if you need to get rid of the form, I would prefer a way to keep the identical gray background color that the form generates. I happen to like the exact shade of gray that the form generates as a background.

Sample Code:

```
struct TestDate: View {
    @State var chosenDate = Date()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $chosenDate, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute, .date])
            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have tried putting spacers around the Form and putting spacers within the Form (both within VStacks). I also checked if `Form` has any parameters I can change on `init`, but unlike `VStack` and `HStack`, there does not appear to be any alignment or spacing parameters on `Form`. Only `content:`

Comment: What have you tried? What part of your code does not produce what you want. This isn’t the place to just request code to be written for you.

Comment: Fair point, will edit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this instead:

```
struct TestDate: View {
    @State var chosenDate = Date()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(red: 236/255, green: 236/255, blue: 236/255, opacity: 1).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                DatePicker("Date", selection: $chosenDate, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute, .date])
                    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .padding(10)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```